# Change the root EBS device of AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I changed the root device of my AWS ec2 instance and now I can't log in, I get: `Permission denied (publickey)`

The new ebs I changed to was also a bootable volume.

Then I created another instance and added the root volume of the first instance as a second volume, I mounted it and when I checked inside the .ssh/authorized_keys of this second volume (which is a perfect copy of the root volume from the first instance) my private keys were there, so I can't understand why I get a `Permission denied (publickey)`

By the way I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377669/can-i-change-the-root-ebs-device-of-my-amazon-ec2-instance).

Comment: Did you note comment in step 3? "[...] as the root e.g. /dev/sda1"? Reading the comments that seems to be what most people missed out on.

Comment: Aye, I did add my ebs device properly (as sda1) otherwise the instance does not even start. I think the problem could be in the permissions of the .ssh folder and subfiles, that must be why I get the error: `Permission denied (publickey)`